# Submit HTML login form with Enter key?

Tags: html, forms

I have been going through many solutions to my issues with other older questions, but I can't seem to implement any of the solutions.

I am trying to create a simple login box using a form, which then loads a particular webpage based on the login info. This is what I currently have;

```
<div class="container">
<form name="login">
<p class="paragraph">Username <input class="login" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="userid"/></p>
<p class="paragraph">Password <input class="login" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pswrd"/></p>
<p class="paragraph"><input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/></p>
</form>
```

```
function check(form)
{
 if(form.userid.value == "pf900" && form.pswrd.value == "password")
  {
    window.open('/pf900_pid/index.htm','_self')
  }
 else if(form.userid.value == "pf350a" && form.pswrd.value == "password")
  {
    window.open('/pf350a_pid/index.htm','_self')
  }
 else
 {
   alert("Error: Wrong username or password")
  }
}
```

My issue is, that I can't seem to work the form so that the enter key will activate the login button. If I change the button to a submit, it just puts the login info in the address bar and doesn't perform the correct action.

Comment: Instead of overriding `onclick` on the button, override `onsubmit` on the form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would you be able to give an example in code, admittedly, I am learning all of this as I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to summarize what everyone has said here and put it in a single answer.

- On the `<form>` element, be sure to use the onSubmit
- Change the input type to submit
- Remove the click handle on the `<input>`

```js
function check() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = document.forms["login"];
  if (form.userid.value == "pf900" && form.pswrd.value == "password") {
    window.open('/pf900_pid/index.htm', '_self')
  } else if (form.userid.value == "pf350a" && form.pswrd.value == "password") {
    window.open('/pf350a_pid/index.htm', '_self')
  } else {
    alert("Error: Wrong username or password")
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form name="login" onSubmit="check()">
    <p class="paragraph">Username <input class="login" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="userid" /></p>
    <p class="paragraph">Password <input class="login" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pswrd" /></p>
    <p class="paragraph"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Heads up, I cleaned it up a bit since I posted it.

Comment: Also, don't forget to set this as the answer if it works for you :-)

Comment: Thanks for that, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the input type as "Submit:

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

and on the Check function, use

```
 event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

please switch your code to this one:

> form method="post" onsubmit="check(this.form)" action="place your
>   function here"
>
> input type="submit" value="Login"/>

button won't work on form element, it is rather use in dom events or showing a modal.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

We can do in two different ways, just change the input type to `submit` or add `onkeypress` event check the enter key like below.

```
<div class="container">
<form name="login" onkeypress="onEnter(event)">
<p class="paragraph">Username <input class="login" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="userid"/></p>
<p class="paragraph">Password <input class="login" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pswrd"/></p>
<p class="paragraph"><input type="submit" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/></p>
</form>
```

onkeypress function block

```
function onEnter(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13)
     check()
}
```